# Android device doesn't vibrate when calling Vibration.vibrate() in HeadlessJS function

Tags: android, react-native

I am successfully using `Vibration.vibrate([1000, 2000], true);` inside a component in a React Native Android app - the device vibrates when this is called.

However I am also using [HeadlessJS](https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android) to launch a notification when the app is in the background or killed:

App.js:

```js
import backgroundNotificationHandler from './src/services/backgroundNotificationListener';
...

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
firebase.messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(backgroundNotificationHandler);
```

backgroundNotificationListener.js:

```js
import { NativeModules, Vibration } from 'react-native';
import { parseTimeStringForNotification } from './parseTime'
import InCallManager from 'react-native-incall-manager';

const backgroundNotificationHandler = async message => {

  console.log(Vibration); // logs the Vibration object

  InCallManager.startRingtone('_BUNDLE_'); // this works
  Vibration.vibrate([1000, 2000], true); // this doesn't work
...
```

Is there any reason this shouldn't work? Is there some kind of OS restriction on this / should I try a third party package here to make the device vibrate?

Comment: did you ever got to a conclusion about this? Having a similar issue with Vibration.vibrate() from BackgroundFetch when app is backgrounded

Comment: Actually no, I still haven't figured it out! My guess is that it doesn't work because React is out of context, but I would imagine it's possible with some native modules trickery. I'll put a bounty on it now and see if we can find out..

Comment: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/731

Comment: InCallManager supports vibration input with `startRingtone` function. It does not support repeat functionality yet but maybe that could work in your case.

Comment: Does your AndroidManifest, or the merged manifest AndroidManifest, declares the permission `android.permission.VIBRATE`?